# Webtile works on WP8.1 but not Android

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-band

I created a WebTile for the Microsoft Band following the instructions [here](http://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20Web%20Tile%20Preview%20Documentation.pdf).  The webtile installs and works on WP8 devices but not Android.  On Android I get the message "The tile is invalid. Please check with the tile source to get the valid file, and then try again."  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it was a casing issue but not with the file "webtile" extension.  I had the path to the icons folder as "Icons" and it was "icons/tileIcon.png" in the manifest.  Apparently WP is okay with the path casing not being perfect and iOS and Android are not.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file extension *.WEBTILE or *.webtile? I noticed that for Android, it currently only works with lower case extension.